# how can i override malloc(), calloc(), free() etc under OS X?

Tags: xcode, macos, malloc, overriding

Assuming the latest XCode and GCC, what is the proper way to override the memory allocation functions (I guess operator new/delete as well). The debugging memory allocators are too slow for a game, I just need some basic stats I can do myself with minimal impact.

I know its easy in Linux due to the hooks, and this was trivial under codewarrior ten years ago when I wrote HeapManager.

Sadly smartheap no longer has a mac version.

Comment: I did find http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/dyld/dyld-46.12/src/dyldNew.cpp for operator new, works great, now to figure out malloc/calloc

Answer (score 10):

I would use library preloading for this task, because it does not require modification of the running program. If you're familiar with the usual Unix way to do this, it's almost a matter of replacing LD_PRELOAD with DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES.

First step is to create a library with code such as this, then build it using regular shared library linking options (`gcc -dynamiclib`):

```
void *malloc(size_t size)
{
    void * (*real_malloc)(size_t);
    real_malloc = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "malloc");

    fprintf(stderr, "allocating %lu bytes\n", (unsigned long)size);
    /* Do your stuff here */

    return real_malloc(size);
}
```

Note that if you also divert `calloc()` and its implementation calls `malloc()`, you may need additional code to check how you're being called. C++ programs should be pretty safe because the `new` operator calls `malloc()` anyway, but be aware that no standard enforces that. I have never encountered an implementation that didn't use `malloc()`, though.

Finally, set up the running environment for your program and launch it (might require adjustments depending on how your shell handles environment variables):

```
export DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=./yourlibrary.dylib
export DYLD_FORCE_FLAT_NAMESPACE=1
yourprogram --yourargs
```

See [the dyld manual page](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/dyld.1.html) for more information about the dynamic linker environment variables.

This method is pretty generic. There are limitations, however:

- You won't be able to divert direct system calls

  If the application itself tricks you by using `dlsym()` to load `malloc`'s address, the call won't be diverted. Unless, however, you trick it back by also diverting `dlsym`!

Answer (score 3):

The `malloc_default_zone` technique mentioned at http://lists.apple.com/archives/darwin-dev/2005/Apr/msg00050.html appears to still work, see e.g. http://code.google.com/p/fileview/source/browse/trunk/fileview/fv_zone.cpp?spec=svn354&r=354 for an example use that seems to be similar to what you intend.

Comment: This is a great example, but I think a cleaner example of completely replacing OSX's memory allocator is available at https://github.com/emeryberger/Heap-Layers/blob/master/wrappers/macwrapper.cpp. Still... that original email thread is awesome. :)

Answer (score 1):

After much searching (here included) and issues with 10.7 I decided to write a blog post about this topic: [How to set malloc hooks in OSX Lion](http://bkdc.ubiquity.ro/2011/07/how-to-set-malloc-hooks-in-osx-lion-107.html)

You'll find a few good links at the end of the post with more information on this topic.

The basic solution:

```
malloc_zone_t *dz=malloc_default_zone();
if(dz->version>=8)
{
    vm_protect(mach_task_self(), (uintptr_t)malloc_zones, protect_size, 0, VM_PROT_READ | VM_PROT_WRITE);//remove the write protection
}
original_free=dz->free;
dz->free=&my_free; //this line is throwing a bad ptr exception without calling vm_protect first
if(dz->version==8)
{
    vm_protect(mach_task_self(), (uintptr_t)malloc_zones, protect_size, 0, VM_PROT_READ);//put the write protection back
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I came across it while trying to do this myself. I got curious about this topic for a personal project I was working on, mainly to make sure that what I thought was automatically deallocated was being properly deallocated. I ended up writing a C++ implementation to allow me to track the amount of allocated heap and report it out if I so chose.

https://gist.github.com/monitorjbl/3dc6d62cf5514892d5ab22a59ff34861

As the name notes, this is OSX-specific. However, I was able to do this on Linux environments using the `malloc_usable_size`

**Example**

```
#define MALLOC_DEBUG_OUTPUT
#include "malloc_override_osx.hpp"

int main(){
   int* ip = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
   double* dp = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double));

   free(ip);
   free(dp);
}
```

**Building**

```
$ clang++ -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk \
          -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -std=gnu++11 -g -o test test.cpp
$ ./test
0x7fa28a403230 -> malloc(16) -> 16
0x7fa28a403240 -> malloc(16) -> 32
0x7fa28a403230 -> free(16) -> 16
0x7fa28a403240 -> free(16) -> 0
```

Hope this helps someone else out in the future!

Answer (score 0):

If the basic stats you need can be collected in a simple wrapper, a quick (and kinda dirty) trick is just using some `#define` macro replacement.

```
void* _mymalloc(size_t size)
{
    void* ptr = malloc(size);

    /* do your stat work? */

    return ptr;
}
```

and

```
#define malloc(sz_) _mymalloc(sz_)
```

**Note**: if the macro is defined *before* the _mymalloc definition it will end up replacing the malloc call inside that function leaving you with infinite recursion... so ensure this isn't the case. You might want to explicitly `#undef` it before that function definition and simply (re)define it afterward depending on where you end up including it to hopefully avoid this situation.

Comment: This won't work with C++ operator new/delete or libraries without source though

Answer (score 0):

I think if you define a malloc() and free() in your own .c file included in the project the linker will resolve that version.

Now then, how do you intend to implement malloc?

Answer (score 0):

Check out Emery Berger's -- the author of the Hoard memory allocator's -- approach for replacing the allocator on OSX at https://github.com/emeryberger/Heap-Layers/blob/master/wrappers/macwrapper.cpp (and a few other files you can trace yourself by following the includes).

This is complementary to Alex's answer, but I thought this example was more to-the-point of replacing the system provided allocator.

Comment: Registering a new default zone works but it's sometimes too much if all you need is some "basic stats", like the question indicates. Hooking into the default zone is easier but it no longer works as described by Alex so why the down-vote without any comment on an answer that only helps solve the issue?