# How to make OS X malloc automatically abort on failure?

Tags: c, macos, malloc

The [Matasano blog](http://mtso.squarespace.com/chargen/2006/1/29/four-c-programming-anti-idioms.html) calls “Checking the return value of `malloc()`” a “C Programming Anti-Idiom.” Instead `malloc()` should automatically call `abort()` for you if it fails. The argument is that, since you’ll usually want to abort the program if `malloc()` fails, that should be the default behaviour instead of something you have to laboriously type—or maybe forget to type!—every time.

Without getting into the merits of the idea, what’s the easiest way to set this up? I’m looking for something that would automatically detect memory allocation failures by other library functions such as [`asprintf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/asprintf) too. A portable solution would be wonderful, but I’d also be happy with something mac-specific.

---

Summarizing the best answers below:

#### Mac run-time solution

Set the `MallocErrorAbort=1` environment variable before running your program. Automatically works for all memory allocation functions.

#### Mac/linux run-time solution

[Use a dynamic library shim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/931866/14558) to load a custom `malloc()` wrapper at runtime with `LD_PRELOAD` or `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES`. You will likely want to wrap `calloc()`, `realloc()`, *&*c. as well.

#### Mac/linux compiled solution

Define your own `malloc()` and `free()` functions, and access the system versions using `dyld(RTLD_NEXT, "malloc")` [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4586534/14558). Again, you will likely want to wrap `calloc()`, `realloc()`, *&*c. as well.

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *(*system_malloc)(size_t) = NULL;

void* malloc(size_t bytes) {
    if (system_malloc == NULL) {
        system_malloc = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "malloc");
    }
    void* ret = system_malloc(bytes);
    if (ret == NULL) {
        perror("malloc failed, aborting");
        abort();
    }
    return ret;
}

int main() {
    void* m = malloc(10000000000000000l);
    if (m == NULL) {
        perror("malloc failed, program still running");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

#### Linux compiled solution

Use `__malloc_hook` and `__realloc_hook` as described in the [glibc manual](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/libc/manual/html_node/Hooks-for-Malloc.html).

#### Mac compiled solution

Use the [`malloc_default_zone()` function](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man3/malloc_default_zone.3.html) to access the heap’s data structure, unprotect the memory page, and install a hook in `zone->malloc`:

```
#include <malloc/malloc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void* (*system_malloc)(struct _malloc_zone_t *zone, size_t size);
static void* my_malloc(struct _malloc_zone_t *zone, size_t size) {
    void* ret = system_malloc(zone, size);
    if (ret == NULL) {
        perror("malloc failed, aborting");
        abort();
    }
    return ret;
}

int main() {
    malloc_zone_t *zone = malloc_default_zone();
    if (zone->version != 8) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unknown malloc zone version %d\n", zone->version);
        abort();
    }
    system_malloc = zone->malloc;
    if (mprotect(zone, getpagesize(), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE) != 0) {
        perror("munprotect failed");
        abort();
    }
    zone->malloc = my_malloc;
    if (mprotect(zone, getpagesize(), PROT_READ) != 0) {
        perror("mprotect failed");
        abort();
    }

    void* m = malloc(10000000000000000l);
    if (m == NULL) {
        perror("malloc failed, program still running");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For completeness you will likely want to wrap `calloc()`, `realloc()`, and the other functions defined in `malloc_zone_t` in `/usr/include/malloc/malloc.h` as well.

Comment: Missed the part about `asprintf` check my answer for a portable way to do this.

Comment: Actually, you can usually do something if you preallocated a small chunk of memory for "emergency purpose". Maybe cleanup some resources or rollbacking a transaction.

Answer (score 5):

Just wrap `malloc()` in some `my_malloc()` function that does this instead. In a lot of cases it's actually possible to handle not being able to allocate memory so this type of behaviour would be undesirable. It's easy to add functionality to `malloc()` but not to remove it, which is probably why it behaves this way.

Another thing to keep in mind is that this is a library you're calling into. Would you like to make a library call and have the library kill your application without you being able to have a say in it?

I guess I missed the part about `asprintf` but libc exports some hooks you can use (what valgrind does essentially) that let you override the malloc behavior. Here's a reference to the hooks themselves, if you know C well enough it's not hard to do.

http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/libc/manual/html_node/Hooks-for-Malloc.html

Comment: Thanks! Knowing about `__malloc_hook` let me Google for the Mac equivalent. BTW Valgrind actually uses something called “dynamic binary recompilation”—the original code is disassembled, instrumentation is added at the machine-instruction level, and the transformed code is recompiled and executed. [Have a look at the paper](http://www.valgrind.org/docs/valgrind2007.pdf), it’s pretty interesting.

Comment: @andrew I know, I said what it does essentially :P (it is a cool paper, I read it before). Valgrind just does this but the hardcore way.

Answer (score 2):

`man malloc` on my Mac gives the following information.   It looks like you want `MallocErrorAbort`.

> #### ENVIRONMENT
>
> The following environment variables change the behavior of the allocation-related functions.
>
> - `MallocLogFile <f>`
>     Create/append messages to the given file path `<f>` instead of writing to the standard error.
> - `MallocGuardEdges`
>     If set, add a guard page before and after each large block.
> - `MallocDoNotProtectPrelude`
>     If set, do not add a guard page before large blocks, even if the MallocGuardEdges environment variable is set.
> - `MallocDoNotProtectPostlude`
>     If set, do not add a guard page after large blocks, even if the MallocGuardEdges environment variable is set.
> - `MallocStackLogging`
>     If set, record all stacks, so that tools like leaks can be used.
> - `MallocStackLoggingNoCompact`
>     If set, record all stacks in a manner that is compatible with the malloc_history program.
> - `MallocStackLoggingDirectory`
>     If set, records stack logs to the directory specified instead of saving them to the default location (/tmp).
> - `MallocScribble`
>     If set, fill memory that has been allocated with 0xaa bytes.  This increases the likelihood that a program making assumptions about the contents of freshly allocated memory will fail.  Also if set, fill memory that has been deallocated with 0x55 bytes.  This increases the likelihood that a program will fail due to accessing memory that is no longer allocated.
> - `MallocCheckHeapStart <s>`
>     If set, specifies the number of allocations `<s>` to wait before beginning periodic heap checks every `<n>` as specified by MallocCheckHeapEach.  If MallocCheckHeapStart is set but MallocCheckHeapEach is not specified, the default check repetition is 1000.
> - `MallocCheckHeapEach <n>`
>     If set, run a consistency check on the heap every `<n>` operations. MallocCheckHeapEach is only meaningful if MallocCheckHeapStart is also set.
> - `MallocCheckHeapSleep <t>`
>     Sets the number of seconds to sleep (waiting for a debugger to attach) when MallocCheckHeapStart is set and a heap corruption is detected.  The default is 100 seconds.  Setting this to zero means not to sleep at all. Setting this to a negative number means to sleep (for the positive number of seconds) only the very first time a heap corruption is detected.
> - `MallocCheckHeapAbort <b>`
>     When MallocCheckHeapStart is set and this is set to a non-zero value, causes abort(3) to be called if a heap corruption is detected, instead of any sleeping.
> - `MallocErrorAbort`
>     If set, causes abort(3) to be called if an error was encountered in malloc(3) or free(3), such as a calling free(3) on a pointer previously freed.
> - `MallocCorruptionAbort`
>     Similar to MallocErrorAbort but will not abort in out of memory conditions, making it more useful to catch only those errors which will cause memory corruption.  MallocCorruptionAbort is always set on 64-bit processes.
> - `MallocHelp`
>     If set, print a list of environment variables that are paid heed to by the allocation-related functions, along with short descriptions.  The list should correspond to this documentation.

Note the comments under `MallocCorruptionAbort` about the behaviour of `MallocErrorAbort`.

---

For most of my own code, I use a series of wrapper functions — `emalloc()`, `erealloc()`, `ecalloc()`, `efree()`, `estrdup()`, etc — that check for failed allocations (`efree()` is a straight pass-through function for consistency) and do not return when an allocation fails.  They either exit or abort.  This is basically what [Jesus Ramos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/392046/jesus-ramos) suggests in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14515068/15168); I agree with what he suggests.

However, not all programs can afford to have that happen.  I'm just in the process of fixing up some code I wrote which does use these functions so that it can be reused in a context where it is not OK to fail to on allocation error.  For its original purpose (security checks during the very early stages of process startup), it was fine to exit on error, but now it needs to be usable after the system is running, when a premature exit is not allowed.  So, the code has to deal with those paths where the code used to be able to assume 'no return on allocation failure'.  That's a tad painful.  It can still take a conservative view; an allocation failure means the request is not safe and process it appropriately.  But not all code can afford to fail with abort on memory allocation failure.

Comment: `MallocErrorAbort=1` is nice, but I can only get it to work if I set it before running the program. Is there a way to turn on that behaviour from within the program itself? And is there a way to make such wrapper scripts work with library functions like `asprintf()` that call `malloc()` internally?

Comment: Is this mac only? I don't remember seeing anything about this in POSIX implementations although I could be wrong.

Comment: It is Mac OS X primarily; it might also be available on other BSD systems.  The question is tagged Mac OS X, and I did state 'man malloc on my Mac' to indicate that it was the Mac OS X documentation.  The Linux implementation of malloc is definitely not the same; it probably doesn't have the hooks in the same way as Mac does.  I'm not sure whether it supports all the features that the Mac version does.